# JSON Library for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I was wondering which iPhone JSON library is best for serializing an object (which will later be read by a Java server). At the moment we're using TouchJSON and I've been told that it can't do serialization.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json-framework`](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) can do serialization.

It's so convenient in that it defines some categories on the objects that you would typically want to convert to JSON, such as `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I use this library too. It's very easy to use. I recommend it!